# Annotation Processing Tool add code to existing class

Tags: java, apt

My goal is to add some source code to existing class using annotations.

First, I create an annotation and then I implemented a `AbstractProcessor` Class.
After that I create the `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file and I generate the JAR file using the export eclipse option.

[image: javax.annotation.processing.Processor file]

When I use my jar in other project I have the following error:

```
Internal compiler error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/source/util/Trees at org.xxx.preprocessor.ActionProcessor.init(ActionProcessor.java:44)
```

And the mentioned line is like the joined picture:

[image: ActionProcessor.java:44]

I want to use tree in order to get the compilation unit and add some code to my annotated function.

So in the first time I don't know how to fix this problem, or another way to do this.

Comment: Please include the code as text in the question, not as pictures.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote an AP tool which is based on Sun internal code but run it inside of the Eclipse IDE. Eclipse comes with it's own Java compiler, so you don't have access to internal Java classes anymore.

I suggest to look at [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) which has the exact same problem and look at their solution. The source hides behind the "Contribute" link: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok

In the `src/` folder is a folder `eclipseAgent/` which should get you started.

Comment: thanks for your response,
So if I use the javac commande  : >
javac -cp myExported.jar 
     SimpleAnnotationsTest.java
it'll work !! 
Because I get JavaModelException

Comment: @jrad You're getting a different exception, so I'd say yes, my answer is correct. If you want to know why you're getting `JavaModelException`, you have to ask a new question and give us all the details.